# SPD Workflow - Create Multiple List Items

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have three lists: a list of companies, a calendar and a task list.

Upon creation of a calendar item, I need a task to be created for each company in the "Companies" list.

Any ideas how to go about this?

Thanks in advance.